# Assert a method is called with MSTEST

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm trying to test not the state but the behavior of some code. Using MSTest can I assert if a certain method is called? May I need to use a mock framework?

In particular now I want to check if a private object is instantiated, without being forced to make it public just for testing, but a solution to check if any method is called would be great for future needings :)

Comment: Why would you wanna test if a private method is called? Why even care? That's an implementation detail. What you wanna unit test is that given some specific input your **PUBLIC** produces the expected output. I mean, today your public method is calling a private method, tomorrow a Win32 unsafe function and the day after tomorrow a web service hosted at the other side of the globe. It doesn't matter as long as the public method behaves as expected. So that's what you should test. On the other hand if you want to unit test your public method in isolation all dependencies should be mocked.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is right, what you want to do is `too much` implementation details. If you can give a small yet representative portion of code and what you want to test exactly it might be more clear.Regarding down vote, I have no idea.I'd rather say that it is legitimate question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing the method you want to really test the *behavior* of the method. This means taking a look at what your method does and writing a test ot maker certain that the data it changes really is changed. For example:

```
public void Bigmethod()
{
   newUpCollections();
   CreateDatabaseConnection();
   FlagBadData();
}
```

If you wanted to verify that newUpCollections works:

```
[TEST]
public void BigMethod_WhenCalled_RecreatesCollections()
{
   BigMethod()

   Assert.IsNotNull(Class.Collections);
}
```

If you method doesn't have any behavior that changes anything you probably don't need to test it and may not even need it in the software. So take a look at your method, what data is it changing and can you monitor that that data is really being changed?